# How to change volume with Python?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, volume

I'm writing a program to wake me up mornings, but I want my program to play alarm sound as loud as its possible. so it needs to raise up volume to 100%. but I don't know how. I'm using `python3` on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust OSX System Audio Volume in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565204/adjust-osx-system-audio-volume-in-python)

Comment: Looks similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565204/adjust-osx-system-audio-volume-in-python

Comment: I also visited [Adjust OS X System Audio Volume in Python](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiyhJP-xePVAhWld5oKHayHBHUQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2565204%2Fadjust-osx-system-audio-volume-in-python&usg=AFQjCNHVf4i2fu8KSNo6NrKguOCl5IeMrg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can control the volume of your computer with Applescript:

```
set volume output volume 100
```

To execute Applescript from python you can use `py-applescript` which can be installed with `sudo easy_install py-applescript`. The following script will set the volume:

```
import applescript

applescript.AppleScript("set volume output volume 100").run()
```

EDIT: For Python3.6 you can use `osascript` instead: `pip3.6 install osascript` and:

```
import osascript

osascript.osascript("set volume output volume 100")
```

Comment: thanks! I installed it by 'sudo pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org py-applescript', but when importing it, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'". I also installed Foundation, but same error when importing.

Comment: I also tried "sudo easy_install-3.6 py-applescript". same error.

Comment: do you know any other way, for python3 and without AppleScript ?

Comment: I asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780836/how-to-control-volume-with-python3)

Comment: @dariushmazlumi: I've added a solution for Python3.6.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need anything outside of the standard library to do this in python. Apple supports executing AppleScript from the terminal so the subprocess module is sufficient.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["osascript -e 'set volume output volume 100'"], shell=True)
```