# how to control volume with python3?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, audio, volume

I wanted to write an alarm program, for waking up in mornings. I want it to play sound as loud as possible, so it needs to raise up volume to 100%. 
I also asked [how to change volume with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772011/how-to-change-volume-with-python). @macmoonshine suggest me to use 'AppleScript'. it was good and worked for me, but it works only on python2(error on python3) and(not sure) only works for apple. how can I write a program that can control volume in python3 without using AppleScript?
I'd appreciate your help(;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change volume with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772011/how-to-change-volume-with-python)

Comment: Check macmoonshine's edited answer to your first question.

Comment: I did!^_^. it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a python2 file with the required code and `os.startfile('Path to ur file')` or `os.system('python2 path-to-file')` from your python2 code, its simple as that.